# Why doesn't this Java loop terminate?

Tags: java, for-loop, terminate

I can't understand why doesn't this loop in Java terminate.

```
long i = 26L ;
long j = 24L ;
for (long x = 0L ; x < 1000L ; x++) {
    i = i / 12 + 23 * (--x ) ;
    j = (x--) + j + 5 ;
}
```

Comment: Count the number of times `x` is decremented in the loop body. Compare it to the number of times `x` is incremented in the update expression.

Comment: ... and consider that the loop termination expression in the `for` statement only has an upper bound, not a lower bound (so effectively the lower bounds is `Long.MIN_VALUE - 1` - so the loop does terminate, it just takes a long time)

Comment: in each iteration you are doing x - 2 and then x + 1 so at the end you are decrementing x by 1 in each iteration. so the calue of x will never cross the one specified in the for loop statement. hence it doesnt terminate

Comment: once i reach nearly -7.5m, eclipse gets an error which is: 'IOConsole Update' has encountered a problem. An internal error has occurred. Further information are Java heap space

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In each iteration of the loop, you are *decrementing* the counter `x` *twice*.  This means practically that the upper bound of the loop will never be hit.  In fact, the counter should go negative even after the first iteration.

This is what you probably intended to do:

```
for (long x = 0L ; x < 1000L ; x++) {
    long xTemp = x;
    i = i / 12 + 23 * (--xTemp ) ;
    j = (--xTemp) + j + 5 ;
}
```

or possibly this:

```
for (long x = 0L ; x < 1000L ; x++) {
    i = i / 12 + 23 * (x-1L) ;
    j = (x-1L) + j + 5 ;
}
```

In general, if you designate `x` as `for` loop counter, then you should not be messing around with it inside the loop as a matter of good practice.  You can use its value inside the loop, but let the loop itself manage it.

Comment: or just use `x-1` instead of using an extra variable

Comment: "should go negative *at some point*" -- it will go negative at the end of the first iteration.

Answer (score 0):

The key is what x-- does ... and what x++ does. x will never reach 1000L.

Comment: Point taken ... and it's an edge case.

Comment: @ScaryWombat It won't reach 1000. It will go from Long.MIN_VALUE to Long.MAX_VALUE, which is greater/equal than 1000 so the loop terminates at that point :-)

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt so true, so true

Answer (score 0):

> I can't understand why doesn't this loop in Java terminate.

well, the variable **x** starts with zero, and on every iteration its value will increase by 1 (by doing **x++**) but decreased twice (by doing **--x**) the arithmetic will be at the end that **x** decreased 1 after every iteration,

Technically speaking x will be some when negative and then **UNDERFLOWS**, at that point in the underflow  **x** will be bigger than zero again and then this condition will be true:  **x < 1000L**

```
for (long x = 0L ; x < 1000L ; x++) {
    i = i / 12 + 23 * (--x ) ;
    j = (x--) + j + 5 ;
}
```